# Rethinkdb replace with getAll

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have a table with users, each row looks like this:

```
{
  id: <user's id>,
  email: <user's email>
}
```

Where `id` is the primary key and there's a secondary index for `email`.

I want to add a user only if no other use with the same email exists. Normally I would use two queries for this: `getAll(<user's email>, {index: 'email'})` to make sure the email is not taken, followed by `insert({email: <user's email>}` but these are two separate queries (i.e. not an atomic operation).

**Is there a way to check-and-set atomically using `getAll`?**

Note: I know it's possible to do it with `get` as shown [here](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/consistency/#linearizability-and-atomicity-guarantees) but that doesn't work with `getAll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do atomic operations on secondary indexes, unfortunately.  The best thing to do would probably be to add another `emails` table where the primary key is the email address.

Comment: Given that this use case is virtually everywhere, what's the best practice here?

Comment: I think the best practice would be a separate `emails` table with the email as the primary key, used to enforce uniqueness.